# Drawing a Rectangular Border around a Text Drawn by GraphicsPath

Tags: c#, .net, text, drawing, gdi+

I'm using the `GraphicPath.Addstring` method to add a string to the graphic path and `Graphics.drawpath` to draw the string.  I want to calculate the width and height of the text drawn so that I can draw a rectangle around the drawn text.  I have tried using `Graphics.MeasureString` and `TextRenderer.MeasureText` to calculate the width and `Graphicpath.addrectangle` and `Graphics.Drawpath` to draw the rectangle, but I'm not able to get the correct dimensions with different fonts.

Please help me solve this.

Comment: can you post some code example?

Answer (score 1):

Add your string to the path then call

`GraphicsPath.GetBounds();`

to determine the region.  This will need to be inflated depending on the pen size used to render the string.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look into [Graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurecharacterranges.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

hope this example helps you

```
var gp = new GraphicsPath();
var g = baseControl.CreateGraphics();
var textSize = g.MeasureString(text, basefont);
gp.AddRectangle(new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), textSize);
gp.AddString("Your String", basefont.FontFamily, basefont.Style, basefont.Size - 0.25f);
```

Answer (score 0):

Little correction :

```
gp.AddRectangle(new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), textSize.ToSize());
```

Comment: Please post this as a comment to the answer you are referring tom once you have enough reputation!